# The result of echo * and echo .*

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

Thereotically, the result of command `echo *` should be "Any file in the current directory". Should it include the dotfile?

Similarly, Should the result of `ls *` include the dotfile?

Comment: What is `list`? Do you mean `ls`?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for the misspelling. I have updated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) section of the GNU bash reference:

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set. When matching a file name, the slash character must always be matched explicitly. In other cases, the ‘.’ character is not treated specially.

This is documented (and expected) behaviour in all POSIX shells, see [Patterns Used for Filename Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13):

> If a filename begins with a period ( '.' ), the period shall be explicitly matched by using a period as the first character of the pattern or immediately following a slash character. The leading period shall not be matched by:
>
> - The asterisk or question-mark special characters
> - A bracket expression containing a non-matching list, such as "[!a]", a range expression, such as "[%-0]", or a character class expression, such as "[[:punct:]]"
>
> It is unspecified whether an explicit period in a bracket expression matching list, such as "[.abc]", can match a leading period in a filename.

Comment: In bash (which is the default shell for most linux distros) you can set the mentioned dotglob option with `shopt -s dotglob`, and then `*` will match files starting with a dot as well as those that don't. Unset it with `shopt -u dotglob`.

Comment: You should mention that the `*` is being expanded by bash (or whatever your shell is) and then passed on to the `echo` or `ls` commands, and **not** the commands themselves.

Comment: @jsbillings Considering the documentation I linked to is that of the bash/POSIX shell manuals, I don't think that's necessary to mention.